# How to get canvas transformation matrix on Edge?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

In a project where I am using a canvas, I need to get the canvas' transformation matrix.

On Chrome and Safari, this is possible using `ctx.getTransform()` (`ctx` being the canvas context object).

However, on Edge, `getTransform()` does not work. Does Edge have another `ctx` method/property that I need to call? Or there isn't any?

**I know this question was asked before, but this was years before**, and what I want is an update on that.

So my question is: Is there *now, in 2019,* a built-in method/property that returns us a canvas' transformation matrix on Edge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't check this, but I think `.getTransform()` is by [HTML5 spec on getTransform()](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#dom-context-2d-gettransform)
and if a browser will implement it, it needs to have this specific signature.
So if you don't see it available, it most likely not implemented in the browser version you are testing.

Though, [HTML5Test states that Edge support `2D Canvas` fully](https://html5test.com/compare/browser/edge/firefox/chrome-68/opera-45/mybrowser.html).